# Oracle Query optimization for huge table for report

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I am trying to get the output of the following query. It's taking forever and no output. Can you please help in optimizing the query? I tried using hint parallel but still no output. TabA has about 1.2 million and TabB 0.7 million records. Database is Oracle.

```
WITH TAB1 as (
SELECT
P_TXN_ID,PROD_CD,P_TYPE1,P_TYPE2,
(SELECT COALESCE(FT.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE,'XX') FROM TabA FT WHERE FT.P_TXN_ID=ST.P_TXN_ID AND FT.P_ROLE='FBO' AND LAST_UPD_DT='20-NOV-17' ) FBO,
(SELECT COALESCE(FT.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE,'XX') FROM TabA FT WHERE FT.P_TXN_ID=ST.P_TXN_ID AND FT.P_ROLE='ORG' AND LAST_UPD_DT='20-NOV-17' ) ORG,
(SELECT COALESCE(FT.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE,'XX') FROM TabA FT WHERE FT.P_TXN_ID=ST.P_TXN_ID AND FT.P_ROLE='SEND' AND LAST_UPD_DT='20-NOV-17' )  SEND,
(SELECT COALESCE(FT.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE,'XX') FROM TabA FT WHERE FT.P_TXN_ID=ST.P_TXN_ID AND FT.P_ROLE='RCV' AND LAST_UPD_DT='20-NOV-17' ) RCV,
(SELECT COALESCE(FT.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE,'XX') FROM TabA FT WHERE FT.P_TXN_ID=ST.P_TXN_ID AND FT.P_ROLE='SCND' AND LAST_UPD_DT='20-NOV-17' ) SCND,
(SELECT COALESCE(FT.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE,'XX') FROM TabA FT WHERE FT.P_TXN_ID=ST.P_TXN_ID AND FT.P_ROLE='BENE' AND LAST_UPD_DT='20-NOV-17' ) BENE,
(SELECT COALESCE(FT.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE,'XX') FROM TabA FT WHERE FT.P_TXN_ID=ST.P_TXN_ID AND FT.P_ROLE='INT1' AND LAST_UPD_DT='20-NOV-17' ) INT1,
(SELECT COALESCE(FT.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE,'XX') FROM TabA FT WHERE FT.P_TXN_ID=ST.P_TXN_ID AND FT.P_ROLE='INT2' AND LAST_UPD_DT='20-NOV-17' ) INT2,
(SELECT COALESCE(FT.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE,'XX') FROM TabA FT WHERE FT.P_TXN_ID=ST.P_TXN_ID AND FT.P_ROLE='INT3' AND LAST_UPD_DT='20-NOV-17' ) INT3,
(SELECT COALESCE(FT.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE,'XX') FROM TabA FT WHERE FT.P_TXN_ID=ST.P_TXN_ID AND FT.P_ROLE='INT4' AND LAST_UPD_DT='20-NOV-17' ) INT4,
(SELECT COALESCE(FT.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE,'XX') FROM TabA FT WHERE FT.P_TXN_ID=ST.P_TXN_ID AND FT.P_ROLE='INT5' AND LAST_UPD_DT='20-NOV-17' ) INT5
FROM 
(SELECT PROD_CD,P_TYPE1,P_TYPE2,LAST_UPD_DT,P_TXN_ID 
FROM TabB
) ST
WHERE LAST_UPD_DT>='20-NOV-17' AND LAST_UPD_DT<='22-NOV-17'  
)

SELECT /*+ parallel(100)*/
COUNT(*),
PROD_CD,
P_TYPE1,
FBO,ORG,SEND,RCV,SCND,BENE,
INT1,INT2,INT3,INT4,INT5
FROM 
TAB1 
GROUP BY PROD_CD,
P_TYPE1,
FBO,ORG,SEND,RCV,SCND,BENE,
INT1,INT2,INT3,INT4,INT5
ORDER BY PROD_CD;
```

Thanks in advance. Just to make things easy, below is the example above query is trying to achieve. Say there is table `TXN` with following data:

```
TXN
Col1 Col2 Col3 Type
1    AA    abc  FBO
2    null  abc  FBO
3    BB    abc  ORG
4    CC    def  ORG
5    DD    def  ORG
6    EE    pqr  SCND
7    EE    pqr  SCND
8    CC    def  RCV
```

Then output of the queries will be:

```
 Col2   Col3 FBO ORG SCND RCV
 AA     abc    1   0    0   0
 null   abc    1   0    0   0
 BB     abc    1   0    0   0
 CC     def    0   1    0   1
 DD     def    0   1    0   0
 EE     pqr    0   0    2   0
```

Comment: Have you check the execution plan? You've al lot of subselects in the select in the with-clause. Are the relevant columns indexed? And you're comparing date columns (at least they look like being of type date) with a string. Which causes implicit type conversion. You don't want that. Use TO_DATE() when comparing with date columns.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, There is little I can do with DB. I am looking to optimize the query

Comment: Use EXPLAIN PLAN to get the execution plan.

Comment: Post the execution plan. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975406/how-to-describe-performance-issue-in-relational-database?answertab=active#tab-top) some hints how to produce it.

Answer (score 1):

I find it hard to follow your code and your explanation.  However, I'm pretty sure that conditional aggregation is all that you need.

Something like this:

```
SELECT b.PROD_CD, b.P_TYPE1, b.P_TYPE2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FT.P_ROLE = 'FBO' THEN a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE END) as FBO,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FT.P_ROLE = 'ORG' THEN a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE END) as ORG,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FT.P_ROLE = 'SEND' THEN a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE END) as SEND,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FT.P_ROLE = 'RCV' THEN a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE END) as RCV,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FT.P_ROLE = 'SCND' THEN a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE END) as SCND,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FT.P_ROLE = 'BENE' THEN a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE END) as BENE,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FT.P_ROLE = 'FBO' THEN a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE END) as FBO,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FT.P_ROLE = 'INT1' THEN a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE END) as INT1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FT.P_ROLE = 'INT2' THEN a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE END) as INT2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FT.P_ROLE = 'INT3' THEN a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE END) as INT3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FT.P_ROLE = 'INT4' THEN a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE END) as INT4
       MAX(CASE WHEN FT.P_ROLE = 'INT5' THEN a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE END) as INT5
FROM TabB b JOIN
     TabA a
      ON a.P_TXN_ID = b.P_TXN_ID AND
         a.LAST_UPD_DT = DATE '2017-11-20'
WHERE LAST_UPD_DT >= DATE '2017-11-20' AND LAST_UPD_DT <= DATE '2017-11-22'
GROUP BY PROD_CD, P_TYPE1, P_TYPE2;
```

Comment: Good point, this will eliminate all possible index issues making a hash join of the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

1. If tabB is partitioned by LAST_UPD_DT or indexed by LAST_UPD_DT, just be sure that '20-NOV-17'and '22-NOV-17' are Dates. For this, use to_date: to_date('22-NOV-2017','dd-mon-yyyy') etc. (It may by an idea to index this column but if you really update records, your updates will be slow.)
2. do not use parallel 100 but parallel 8 or 16. 100 is too heavy and it may cripple the database.
3. do you need order by PROD_CD? why? It will by faster without it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the execution plan so only guess based recommendation are possible.

Here a check list:

1) The table  `TABA` is not indexed - obviously leading to lot of `FULL TABLE SCAN`s

2) The table  `TABA` is inappropriately indexed  - e.g. there is an index on  P_ROLE, LAST_UPD_DT  which doesn't help, because   P_TXN_ID is missing or

only the column P_TXN_ID is indexed and you have to scan a large number or row before you match the role and date

3) The table  `TABA` is appropriately indexed, i.e. on P_TXN_ID,  P_ROLE, LAST_UPD_DT  but you process a large number of rows in `TABB`

Example to process 100K row from `TABB` you need 100K * 11 = 1.1M (you subquery count) `index access`. For large table with index on disc you will get no more that about 100 row per second. So 
you will be far better to get rid of it, perform a hash join of your tables.

Last but not least - *your approach with parallel is similar to the case when your tires are empty and you react with full throttle*.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your sample data to result, you just need "conditional aggregates" , basically this means for your query `count(case when ... then 1 end)` as follows:

```
SELECT
    col2
  , col3
  , COUNT( CASE WHEN type = 'FBO'  THEN 1 END ) AS FBO
  , COUNT( CASE WHEN type = 'ORG'  THEN 1 END ) AS ORG
  , COUNT( CASE WHEN type = 'SCND' THEN 1 END ) AS SCND
  , COUNT( CASE WHEN type = 'RCV'  THEN 1 END ) AS RCV
FROM txn
GROUP BY
    col2
  , col3
ORDER BY
    col2
  , col3
```

and the result is:

```
+----+------+------+-----+-----+------+-----+
|    | COL2 | COL3 | FBO | ORG | SCND | RCV |
+----+------+------+-----+-----+------+-----+
|  1 | AA   | abc  |   1 |   0 |    0 |   0 |
|  2 | BB   | abc  |   0 |   1 |    0 |   0 |
|  3 | CC   | def  |   0 |   1 |    0 |   1 |
|  4 | DD   | def  |   0 |   1 |    0 |   0 |
|  5 | EE   | pqr  |   0 |   0 |    2 |   0 |
|  6 | NULL | abc  |   1 |   0 |    0 |   0 |
+----+------+------+-----+-----+------+-----+
```

so you can do this:

```
SELECT
    b.PROD_CD
  , b.P_TYPE1
  , b.P_TYPE2
  , COUNT( CASE WHEN FT.P_ROLE = 'FBO'  THEN a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE END ) AS FBO
  , COUNT( CASE WHEN FT.P_ROLE = 'ORG'  THEN a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE END ) AS ORG
  , COUNT( CASE WHEN FT.P_ROLE = 'SEND' THEN a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE END ) AS SEND
  , COUNT( CASE WHEN FT.P_ROLE = 'RCV'  THEN a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE END ) AS RCV
  , COUNT( CASE WHEN FT.P_ROLE = 'SCND' THEN a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE END ) AS SCND
  , COUNT( CASE WHEN FT.P_ROLE = 'BENE' THEN a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE END ) AS BENE
  , COUNT( CASE WHEN FT.P_ROLE = 'FBO'  THEN a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE END ) AS FBO
  , COUNT( CASE WHEN FT.P_ROLE = 'INT1' THEN a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE END ) AS INT1
  , COUNT( CASE WHEN FT.P_ROLE = 'INT2' THEN a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE END ) AS INT2
  , COUNT( CASE WHEN FT.P_ROLE = 'INT3' THEN a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE END ) AS INT3
  , COUNT( CASE WHEN FT.P_ROLE = 'INT4' THEN a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE END ) AS INT4
  , COUNT( CASE WHEN FT.P_ROLE = 'INT5' THEN a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE END ) AS INT5
FROM TabB b
JOIN TabA a ON a.P_TXN_ID = b.P_TXN_ID
AND a.LAST_UPD_DT = DATE '2017-11-20'
WHERE LAST_UPD_DT >= DATE '2017-11-20' AND LAST_UPD_DT <= DATE '2017-11-22'
GROUP BY
    PROD_CD
  , P_TYPE1
  , P_TYPE2;
```

But do note that IF `a.V_PARTY_ID_TYPE` is NULL then the count will NOT increment by 1.